# How to pass a variable value as keyword argument key?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I need to pass the value of a variable as a key of keyword agument.

```
def success_response(msg=None,**kwargs):
    output = {"status": 'success',
        "message": msg if msg else 'Success Msg'}
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        output.update({key:value})
    return output


the_key = 'purchase'
the_value = [
    {"id": 1,"name":"Product1"},
    {"id": 2,"name":"Product2"}
]

success_response(the_key=the_value)
```

actual output is

```
{'status': 'success', 'message': 'Success Msg', 'the_key': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Product1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Product2'}]}
```

expected output is

```
{'status': 'success', 'message': 'Success Msg', 'purchase': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Product1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Product2'}]}
```

I tried `eval()`

`success_response(eval(the_key)=the_value)`

but got the exception
`SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
success_response(**{the_key: the_value})
```

Instead of:

```
success_response(the_key=the_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` in this line:

```
for key,value in kwargs.items():
```

is the name of the keyword argument. In this case, `key` will be `the_key` which means the dictionary `value` passed to `output.update(value)` will be

```
[
    {"id": 1,"name":"Product1"},
    {"id": 2,"name":"Product2"}
]
```

I think what you really want is:

```
success_response(purchase=the_value)
```